# Error in trying to pull information off instragram

Tags: r, api, instagram, instagram-api

I've been working on a project with the hopes of pulling off instagram post and comment information from instagram posts over the past year.

I am starting right now with a simple code just to pull out information from a single user.

Here is the code:

```
require(httr)
full_url <- oauth_callback()
full_url <- gsub("(.*localhost:[0-9]{1,5}/).*", x=full_url,     replacement="\1")
print(full_url)

app_name <- "Cognitive Model of the Customer"
client_id <- "b03d4a910f0442b9bd1cd79fc06a086f"
client_secret <- "c35f785784fa45cd9eaf786742ae9b3f"
scope = "basic"

instagram <- oauth_endpoint(
  authorize = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize",
  access = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token")
myapp <- oauth_app(app_name, client_id, client_secret)

ig_oauth <- oauth2.0_token(instagram, myapp,scope="basic",  type =     "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",cache=FALSE)
tmp <- strsplit(toString(names(ig_oauth$credentials)), '"')
token <- tmp[[1]][4]
library(jsonlite)
library(RCurl)
user_info <- fromJSON(getURL(paste('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?  q=',"newbalance",'&access_token=',token,sep="")),unexpected.escape = "keep")
```

The error I am receiving is

```
Error in simplify(obj, simplifyVector = simplifyVector, simplifyDataFrame =     simplifyDataFrame,  : 
  unused argument (unexpected.escape = "keep")
```

I'm not sure I understand where this error comes from though.

Comment: It comes from your last line. You are passing the `unexpected.escape = "keep"` argument to fromJSON

Comment: what can be done to fix the error though? I need that line there, right?

Answer (score 0):

Before running your code you should load essential packages.
Please load this package and then run your code:
library(rjson)